# Android SDK Support Repository Won't Update

Tags: android

I'm trying to build a script that automatically updates the Android SDK when updates are available, but I'm having trouble.

When I execute the command `android list sdk` from the command line I get the following output:

```
Packages available for installation or update: 1
    1- Android Support Repository, revision 40
```

Then I execute `android update sdk --no-ui` and get the following output:

```
Installing Archives:
  Preparing to install archives
  Downloading Android Support Repository, revision 40
  Installing Android Support Repository, revision 40
    Installed Android Support Repository, revision 4099%)
  Done. 1 package installed.
```

Then I execute `android sdk list` again and get:

```
Packages available for installation or update: 1
    1- Android Support Repository, revision 40
```

When I go into the GUI it shows that the package is installed.

Is there a step I am missing here when updating the Android SDK from the command line?

I'm using a Mac - Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that for some reason, there was a permissions issue with one of the directories.

I wiped the `ANDROID_HOME` directory (in my case `~/android-sdk-linux`) and reinstalled the tools. Works great now!